# tty problem: binary mess instead of "text good data"

Tags: tty, stty

I am trying to use a GPS over moxa Uport 1110 usb-to-serial device. The driver of UPort was installed OK, and GPS sends NMEA (text) data. However, when I issue command

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

my terminal (it is in UTF8 locale if it matters) shows some binary mess. Under windows (so, with a different driver, though both are official) it behaves OK and I can see the data and access GPS.

I wonder if the problem is in some terminal setting.

I previosuly issued stty ispeed 9600, that is what GPS is also configured for reliably; also I tried stty ispeed from low to high, just getting different kind of mess.

Sporadically, good text was shown in some rare attempts.

My current terminal settings are:

```
 [root@blade gpsd-3.14]# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 
 speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
 eof = ^A; min = 1; time = 0;
 -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
 -opost -onlcr
 -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

I appreciate any help in detecting where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (which admittedly is from a number of years ago), physical line characteristics reset back to the defaults when the device is closed. So running `stty ... < /dev/ttyUSB0` as a standalone command is frustratingly pointless because as soon as the command completes the device is closed and it resets back to its default.

To resolve this one had to do something like this

```
sleep 3600 </dev/ttyUSB0 &    # Open the device and keep it open (for 1hr)
stty ... </dev/ttyUSB0        # Set the desired characteristics
cat /dev/ttyUSB0              # Read from the device
...
kill %1                       # Finished with the "sleep"
```

Comment: If that's the problem, then `(stty ispeed 9600; cat) < /dev/ttyUSB0` should work.  Optionally, specify `/dev/ttyUSB0` as an argument to either or both commands.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not the case on Linux.  I have recently made heavy use of `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 foo; cat >/dev/ttyUSB0` constructions.  The terminal settings stay until you change them again, even if the device file is closed and re-opened... though not if you unplug your USB serial device.